# Suggestion for changing the vote/accept icons

Tags: discussion

I'm not sure that most (new) users know how to properly use the vote and accept icons that appear in answers. I know that I didn't for quite some time.

I'd like to propose a minor change in the vote and accept icons...

```
 ^       or        ^        or      vote ^
 0              vote=0                   0
 v                 v                vote v
vote
```

and

```
checkmark icon (as it is now)
Accept
```

Comment: If the text "vote" goes between the upvote and downvote arrows, where should the post score go?

Comment: @EliahKagan good point. I'll change my question.

Comment: This is indeed a good suggestion for the accept icon one. Lots of people have their problem solved, but sometimes they don't remember to accept an answer, such that other people knows that the problem is *actually* solved.

Comment: It's amazing to me that some people can down vote a suggestion, but not have the courage to say why.

Comment: The sum of votes is more accurately described as the post "score", although the action can be described as a vote (we vote or cast a vote). The text "vote=5" etc would be, for me, really confusing as the word "vote" doesn't describe the sum of votes in any normal context, and where negative voting exists this becomes decidedly unintuitive imho. We need a preposition to say *how* we voted on a post (up/down and not for/against). Arguably only your second design has this problem, but the others are really noisy, and given the tooltips for the chevrons, unnecessarily so I think

Answer (score 5):

I believe this is an issue that would affect all StackExchange sites and therefore is a much better fit for the general [Meta StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).

Still, I can not support this proposal (**only this is the meaning of a downvote on Meta**) because I feel that existing icons are sufficiently explained in the [**Tour**](https://askubuntu.com/tour) which we expect all new users to read.

[image]

Sadly not everybody does as judged from the low count of ["informed"](https://askubuntu.com/help/badges/138/informed) badge holders in relation to the user count. This would not improve from a new icon layout. In addition to that an explanatory pop-up for those who don't care about the Tour already exists.

In summary I feel that a new icon layout on Ask Ubuntu would be an issue for the harmonised network-wide user experience and may not really be needed.